# Google classroom doesn't have access to Google Drive

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-classroom

Well i got the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352747/google-classroom-test-account-does-not-have-google-drive-access

Is there any way to access Google drive on a Google Classroom test account?

This is the error when creating a assignment with a google drive file.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The caller does not have permission",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "The caller does not have permission",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i fixed this by getting a real teacher/student account

Answer (score 0):

No, google classroom is a separate google program from Drive. Classroom is a set of folders that everyone in that classroom share.

Comment: I know but you can add Google Drive files to a assignment. The problem is that a test account can't access the files. Even if it is public, it can't open it. Same issue in the browser. When opening a Google Drive file, a normal account can open it and see the logged in user information. But if you open the link with the test account, you can't see any information about the user.

Comment: If a test account can't access the information, does it have proper access to it. Is that account in the classroom, or is there a restriction on that account that doesn't let him view certain files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/DriveFile) in Google Classroom.

> Representation of a Google Drive file.
>
> ```
> {
>   "id": string,
>   "title": string,
>   "alternateLink": string,
>   "thumbnailUrl": string,
> }
> ```

Just be noted that test accounts will expire after 30 days and **do not allow users to access Google apps** other than Classroom. You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/access) for reference.

Comment: I already know that.. but the problem is that i always get a error when i create a assignment with a google drive file (see question). It doesn't happen when using another account but then i don't have classroom access.